# How to push images to GitHub Packages using GITHUB_TOKEN secret with Maven Jib plugin?

Tags: docker, maven, github, github-actions, jib

I want to push a Docker image built with [Maven Jib plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin) to GitHub Packages.

I read that I can use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret for authentication in GitHub Packages.

But I can't find a way to authenticate with a token in Jib documentation.

I only see a way to do it with username and password.

```xml
<settings>
  ...
  <servers>
    ...
    <server>
      <id>MY_REGISTRY</id>
      <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
      <password>{MY_SECRET}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

How can I authenticate with a token using Maven jib plugin?

Answer (score 1):

lDisclaimer: I have never heard of GitHub Packages before.

According to the example on the GitHub Packages website that shows some Docker CLI commands including `docker login` below,

```
$ docker login docker.pkg.github.com --username phanatic
Logged in successfully

$ docker tag app docker.pkg.github.com/phanatic/repo/app:1.0

$ docker push docker.pkg.github.com/phanatic/repo/app:1.0.0
```

I think `MY_REGISTRY` should be `docker.pkg.github.com` and `MY_USERNAME` should be your username (`phanatic` in the example above). Also your `<to><image>` (the target Docker image name) should start with `docker.pkg.github.com/<your username >/...`, as above.

The GitHub Packages docs ([here](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages) and [here](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/using-github-packages-with-github-actions)) seem to suggest that you can use `GITHUB_TOKEN` as a password in GitHub Actions. I strongly recommend you encrypt the password value (`GITHUB_TOKEN`) for `<password>` in `settings.xml`. See the [Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) for how to do so. You will need to create `settings-security.xml`.

Before using `settings.xml` and `settings-security.xml`, I would first locally test the username and `GITHUB_TOKEN` combination with `<to><auth><username>` and `<to><auth><password>` (unencrypted) for the purpose of checking if these values work.

Comment: `GITHUB_TOKEN` is a [secret provided by default when using GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/authenticating-with-the-github_token). I know that the Maven Jib plugin supports a standard username:pwd Docker login. But I want to authenticate specifically with `GITHUB_TOKEN`. I don't want to use my personal account username:pwd for it.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages and https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/using-github-packages-with-github-actions. I think you can just use `GITHUB_TOKEN` as password.

Comment: I can't find any place in those documents where it's written that I can use the token as a password or at least an example of it. That would be strange. But I can try.

Comment: The "Configuring Docker for use with GitHub Packages" doc says "Authenticating with the GITHUB_TOKEN
If you are using a GitHub Actions workflow, you can use a GITHUB_TOKEN to publish and consume packages in GitHub Packages without needing to store and manage a personal access token. For more information, see Authenticating with the GITHUB_TOKEN."